# MySQL Select where field contains one string but not another

Tags: mysql, search

I have to build a search query for a product database which contains two similarly named products with names that look like these examples:

"Widget Simulator and Virtual Seminar for ..."

"Widget Simulator for ..."

Currently if someone searches for "Widget Simulator" they get both types of products in the list. 
I'm trying to build a query that would resemble "Widget Simulator not:Virtual Seminar" that would omit the products that contain the words "Virtual Seminar"

The existing query looks like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS `numrows` 
FROM (`content_product`) 
JOIN `content` ON `content`.`content_id` = `content_product`.`content_id` 
WHERE `content`.`version_status_id` = 28 
AND `content`.`status` = 11
AND `name`  LIKE '%widget%simulator%'
```

I've tried the following, but it doesn't work:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS `numrows` 
FROM (`content_product`) 
JOIN `content` ON `content`.`content_id` = `content_product`.`content_id` 
WHERE `content`.`version_status_id` = 28 
AND `content`.`status` = 11
AND `name`  LIKE '%widget%simulator%'
AND `name` NOT LIKE '%virtual%seminar%'
```

This doesn't work.  I think I understand why it doesn't work, but I cannot find anything here or elsewhere that tells me how to do this.

To summarize, I want to display all products whose name contains "Widget Simulator" while omitting those that also contain "Virtual Seminar".

Thanks for any help or advice.

Comment: I think it should work as you've written it. Can you post some sample data at sqlfiddle.com. See my fiddle for a simplified case [here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0d725/1).

Answer (score 0):

Only personal opinion that I think you should use sub query to use this by first remove all product contain Virtual Seminar then select the rest which contain Widget Simulator, like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS `numrows` 
  FROM (`content_product`) 
  JOIN `content` ON `content`.`content_id` = `content_product`.`content_id` 
 WHERE `content`.`version_status_id` = 28 
   AND `content`.`status` = 11
   AND `name`  LIKE '%widget%simulator%'
   AND `content_product.id` NOT IN (
           SELECT `content_product.id` 
             FROM `content_product` 
            WHERE `name` LIKE '%virtual%seminar%'
       )
```